# sphinxQL + sphinxsearch table doesn't exists

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxapi

Установил `sphinxsearch` -> настроил конфиг -> создал индекс `forum_index` через `indexer --all`. Записи были проиндексированы все без ошибок. Подключил в проекте `SphinxQL`. Установил параметры и делаю запрос согласно примеру в *ReadMe* либы:

```
// create a SphinxQL Connection object to use with SphinxQL
$conn = new Connection();
$conn->setParams(array('host' => 'localhost', 'port' => 9306));
```

Но неожиданно появилась ошибка вида

> access denied www-data@localhost password NO

Указал явно пользователя и пароль внутри либы в месте вызова

```
mysqli::real_connect()
```

Передав туда параметры host, username и т.д. к базе подключило. Теперь при выполнении запроса:

```
$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('column_one', 'colume_two')
    ->from('forum_index');
$result = $query->execute();
```

а в ответ ошибка

> table forum_index doesn't exists

Подскажите, в какую сторону можно копать? Такое чувство, что просто либа не юзает конфиг sphinx и вообще никак не взаимодействует со сфинксом.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему указав в конфиге SphinxQL в качестве хоста явный адрес 127.0.0.1